# Instantiate text and buttons within ScrollRect for Unity3D?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I started off with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWOvwegLDl0).

I'm trying to make buttons and text instantiate within the scrollrect, (think text adventure-ish). Essentially I need a button to instantiate a specific body of text that I input. i.e. I click a button that says "go right" and a body of text instantiates below the existing text that describes what happens after you go right, including new buttons after that new text appears.

I've also got a little progress with [this](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/creating-scroll-lists-at-run-time) Unity tutorial, but it doesn't help with text at all, and the formatting gets weird really quick.

Hopefully the final product will be a story that, at any time, you can scroll up to see what choices you made, etc.

Any ideas and/or tutorials that you know of would be a big help! Thank you!

Comment: SO is not the right place to find tutorial

Comment: Any ideas on how to get it started at least?

Comment: Google could be the right place to search @Vreiche

Comment: I can answer you if you tell me you do you want to instantiate buttons and text  that end up in a gui list on screen and user can scroll it at runtime? thy curious.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just going to put text and buttons within an image and make a prefab, similar to the ui tutorial. Do you think that will work?